# Learning Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As it stands now, I'm a Java and C# developer. The more and more I look at Ruby on Rails, the more I really want to learn it.

What have you found to be the best route to learn RoR?  Would it be easier to develop on Windows, or should I just run a virtual machine with Linux?

Is there an IDE that can match the robustness of Visual Studio?  Any programs to develop that give a good overhead of what to do? Any good books?

Seriously, any tips/tricks/rants would be awesome.

Comment: For an IDE Aptana works great for Windows with Git support (for windows).  However, it will give you major headaches in that the Rails community doesn't care much for Window and it tends to need a lot of work-arounds or hacks of Gems.  I would just say go the PHP route...runs on everything, much more stable, much more flexible, and less of a headache on upgrading systems.

Comment: To anyone else who comes here now, I am just like the OP, a C#/asp.net-mvc dev, trying ruby. It was really hard trying to work in ubuntu so I got everything installed on windows. A few people have told me so far it might be an issue but today I pushed a simple app on heroku.com from windows no problems. As for an IDE, I believe  a good one really helps you learn the framework.  [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) compares to visual studio and you set it with the predefined VS shortcuts and you can hit F12 and inspect and learn the ROR framework. =)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

I've been moving from C# in my professional career to looking at Ruby and RoR in my personal life, and I've found linux to be slightly more appealing personally for development.  Particularly now that I've started using git, the implementation is cleaner on linux.

Currently I'm dual booting and getting closer to running Ubuntu full time.  I'm using gedit with various plugins for the development environment. And as of late 2010, I'm making the push to use Vim for development, even over Textmate on OS X.

A large amount of the Rails developers are using (gasp) Macs, which has actually got me thinking in that direction.

Although I haven't tried it, [Ruby in Steel](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/) gives you a Ruby IDE inside the Visual Studio world, and [IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/) is the .NET flavor of Ruby, if you're interested.

As far as books are concerned, the *[Programming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/programming-ruby-3)* (also known as the Pickaxe) book from the Pragmatic Programmers is the de-facto for learning Ruby.  I bit the bullet and purchased that book and *[Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)*; both books have been excellent.

[Peepcode](http://peepcode.com/) screencasts and PDF books have also been great for getting started; at $9 per screencast it's hard to go wrong.  I actually bought a 5-pack.

Also check out the following:

- [Official Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)
- [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/)
- [railsapi.com](http://railsapi.com/) or [Ruby on Rails - APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails)
- [The Ruby Show](http://rubyshow.com/)
- [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org)
- [Softies on Rails](http://www.softiesonrails.com/) - Ruby on Rails for .NET Developers
- [Rails Podcast](http://podcast.rubyonrails.org/)
- [Rails Best Practices](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-best-practices)

I've burned through the backlog of Rails and Rails Envy podcasts in the past month and they have provided wonderful insight into lots of topics, even regarding software development in general.

Comment: I used to save all my high end hardware for Windows and run Ubuntu Linux on my lower spec hardware. After a while I stopped wasting good hardware on Windows.

Comment: I've used PCs, various flavors of Unix and Macs for my Ruby development, and went with Mac for my personal machine. I love Ubuntu, and consider it a great OS and development platform but there's a tiny bit more icing on the Mac's cake that my music and photography take advantage of. So, either Ubuntu, Ubuntu Mint or Mac OS get my recommendation.

Comment: I added Rails Guides at the top because that's the best place to get started and guaranteed to stay up to date.  I moved softies and Rails podcast to the bottom because they are broken or not active.

Comment: +1 for the shout toward Linux, even if you run it in a VM. Ubuntu is pretty poor for Rails from my experience, unless you are comfortable compiling Ruby from source. Vim is awesome. Textmate on Mac was nice, but once you go Vim you won't go back.

Answer (score 125):

Beware, the rails world is a massively frustrating mess of outdated and inconsistent documentation and examples.  It is maybe one of the fastest moving and most faddish development communities there is.  By the time you learn something it will already have changed.  Even the books are not consistent in which version of rails they are talking about.  Documentation by blogging!  enough said.

I currently do RoR on windows.  My advice is to avoid windows if you can.  Lots of things don't work and the rails community really really doesn't care about you.  The move to Git has really messed me up since it doesn't work very well on windows.  A lot of gems will fail because of this (Heroku looks like a cool tool - too bad for me it can't handle window's Git setup).  Capistrano is out.  It goes on and annoyingly on.

Plus, in the back of your mind, you always wonder when something doesn't work "Is it a rails/windows problem?"  I am not sure this is solved by using linux because linux brings its own hassles like constantly having to upgrade all those different dependencies, etc...If that's the kind of thing you enjoy it might be an okay choice for you.  Those days of enjoying system fiddling are behind me and I just want to get on with doing my work.  I am planning on installing ubuntu on a home machine just so i can get familiar with things like capistrano so maybe my opinion will change.

I'd highly suggest if you are going to do rails dev for any amount of time you seriously consider getting a Mac.  If you value your time and sanity it will pay for itself almost instantly.  Depending on how you value your time 10 hours of debugging windows/linux setup problems and you have spend as much as a Mac costs anyway.

Rails is a joy compared to what it replaces but it is a bit of a pain in that its proponents skip right past a lot of the boring but important stuff like documentation, compatibility issues and community building.  It is way more powerful than other frameworks like Django but I sometimes look over at the Django documentation and community and sigh like a guy with a wild sexy girlfriend looking at his friend's plain but sane and stable wife.  But then rails adds a feature and I go "Ohhh shiny!"

IMO the Rails Screencasts are better than the Peepcode screencasts.  RubyPlus also has screencasts, mind you, they are bit rough around the edges.  BuildingWebApps has a free online course that starts doing screencasts halfway through.

Comment: It's been pretty smooth for me on Ubuntu/Linux. Dependencies auto install (gems and through apt-get.)

Comment: The book agile developmment with rails really does keep pace with RoR, IMHO

Comment: It's mid-2009 and I've been struggling a lot to deploy certain gems and dependencies on Windows.  Ruby itself doesn't have the latest windows installer when compared to other languages. There should be a sticker somewhere on the Ruby and Rails sites which says `best developed under Linux or Mac`.  Failure to comply to that might cause a lot of yak shaving.

Comment: I'm currently learning rails and the first step I took was setting up a Linux VM to use as my dev/test server so that I didn't have to mess with the Vista host OS I am running.  If you are interested in setting up a Linux dev VM for rails feel free to follow my guide: http://www.sharingatwork.com/2009/10/get-started-building-web-apps-with-your-own-ruby-on-rails-virtual-development-server/

Comment: March 10 now and developing on Windows is ok for me.

Comment: you can deploy to heroku just fine from the windows environment, its just that windows doesn't support ssh out of the box so you have to use git-bash or cygwin. follow the guide at help.github.com to get ssh keyphrases working from windows.

Comment: Rails 3 has helped streamline development, and the Rails docs and videos help. There is a huge amount of cruft on the internet regarding old Rails development, and it's a shame we can't flush the toilet and have it disappear. Those sites caused me no end of frustration when I started learning Rails.

Comment: @srboisvert, "Those days of enjoying system fiddling are behind me and I just want to get on with doing my work." Oh so true brother! Amen!

Comment: The stability and quality of the information for learning Rails has improved considerably in the three and half years since this comment was posted, but some of the points about Windows still have some resonance. The Rails courses at http://www.codeschool.com are an excellent place to start.

Comment: -1 to Mac.  We use Macs at work and we spend an inordinate amount of time setting up dev environments.  In my experience it is much easier to script the setup of dev environments on Ubuntu / Mint.

Answer (score 96):

Path of least resistance:

- Have a simple web project in mind.
- Go to **rubyonrails.org** and look at their "Blog in 15 minutes" screencast to get excited.
- Get a copy of O'Reilly Media's **Learning Ruby**
- Get a Mac or Linux box.
  (Fewer early Rails frustrations due to the fact that Rails is generally developed on these.)
- Get a copy of **Agile Web Development with Rails**.
- Get the version of Ruby and Rails described in that book.
- Run through that book's first section to get a feel for what it's like.
- Go to **railscasts.com** and view at the earliest videos for a closer look.
- Buy **The Rails Way** by Obie Fernandez to get a deeper understanding of Rails and what it's doing.
- Then upgrade to the newest production version of Rails, and view the latest railscasts.com videos.

Comment: And add using RVM to help reduce the friction.

Answer (score 24):

I wrote a post called ["Getting Started With Rails -- What I wish I knew"](http://betterexplained.com/articles/starting-ruby-on-rails-what-i-wish-i-knew/) that many people found helpful.

The basics:

- Agile development with Rails (book)
- InstantRails for quick ruby/rails environment on Windows
- Aptana as the IDE
- Subversion for version control

The online tutorials are decent but scattered. Invest $30 in a book for a more comprehensive understanding.

Comment: It looks like the last InstantRails update was on 2007-12-28. http://rubyforge.org/projects/instantrails/

Comment: do not use windows  Just put ubuntu as a dual boot.  It will take less than an hour.  For Aptana - I went from that 2 netbeans 2 rubyMine. Sabe yourself the time. Subversion??? no, use git.  at very least git-svn if your ork uses svn right now.

Answer (score 20):

I've found http://railstutorial.org/book to be a great resource for learning Rails

Answer (score 14):

I really enjoy RubyMine from Jetbrains. It seems like a very full featured IDE something I miss from many of the other alternatives out there. Also for a simple env I enjoy e the text editor. Plain and simple.

Comment: RubyMine 3 is absolutely great, especially if you're coming from C#. RubyMine is made by the same company that built ReSharper.

Answer (score 13):

```
IDE: NetBeans
Book: Agile Web Development With Rails
Installation: Instant Rails
```

Comment: NetBeans is a great all-rounder IDE, but it is slow and crash a lot on my Mac. I would rather recommend TextMate (not free, though)

Comment: I would not go with an IDE when using rails - use VIM, Textmate, or Emacs

Comment: No IDE? Says who? I've used various IDEs, and most of them bring very helpful features to the table. All these guys trying to say you should go hard-core with some plain old editor need to be a little less opinionated about it.

Comment: NetBeans no longer supports ruby: http://netbeans.org/community/news/show/1507.html

Answer (score 12):

1. **[Data Structures and Algorithms with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in Ruby](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus8/html/book.html)**
      Bruno R. Preiss |
      Published in 2004
2. **[Learn to Program](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/)**
      Chris Pine | Pragmatic Bookshelf
      Published in 2006, 176 pages
3. **[Mr. Neighborly's Humble Little Ruby Book](http://www.linuxinsight.com/files/humble_little_ruby_book.pdf)**
      Jeremy McAnally |
      Published in 2006, 147 pages
4. **[Programming Ruby: A Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://www.rubycentral.com/book/)**
      David Thomas, Andrew Hunt | Addison-Wesley
      Published in 2000, 608 pages
5. **[Rails in a Nutshell](http://rails-nutshell.labs.oreilly.com/)**
      C. Fauser, J. MacAulay, E. Ocampo-Gooding, J. Guenin | O'Reilly Media
      Published in 2009, 352 pages
6. **[Ruby Best Practices](http://rubybestpractices.com/)**
      Gregory T. Brown | O'Reilly Media
      Published in 2009, 328 pages
7. **[Ruby Essentials](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Essentials)**
       | Techotopia
      Published in 2007
8. **[Ruby on Rails Security](http://www.rorsecurity.info/the-book)**
      Heiko Webers | OWASP
      Published in 2009, 48 pages
9. **[Ruby User's Guide](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/UsersGuide/rg/)**
      Mark Slagell |
      Published in 2005
10. **[The Book Of Ruby](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/the-book-of-ruby)**
       Huw Collingbourne |
       Published in 2009, 425 pages
11. [**The Little Book of Ruby**](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/IMG/pdf/LittleBookOfRuby.pdf)
       Huw Collingbourne | Dark Neon Ltd.
       Published in 2008, 87 pages
12. **[why's (poignant) guide to Ruby](http://poignantguide.net/ruby/)**
       why the lucky stiff |
       Published in 2008

Comment: Great list! This post talks about a few other good rails books like The Rails 3 Way, Crafting Rails Applications, etc: http://blog.ashchan.com/archive/2011/08/21/learn-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 9):

There's a very solid [ongoing series on NETTUTS](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/learn-ruby-on-rails-from-scratch-week-1/) right now that you may be interested in.

Answer (score 9):

http://railsforzombies.org/ is a nice one. Introducing an all new way to learn Ruby on Rails in the browser with no additional configuration needed.

Answer (score 7):

As you, I'm a java/C# developer trying to learn more Ruby On Rails.

I'm taking the free online course [Ruby on Rails Programming with Passion](http://www.javapassion.com/rubyonrails/), is a good introductory course, check it out.

We are using [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) as IDE (win/mac/linux/solaris), if you are used to Eclipse or Visual Studio, there is a good chance you will like it.

Answer (score 7):

Fantastic decision! It is extremely useful to get a grounding in Ruby before going to Rails so here is my take on the best path to Rails:

- [Learn to Program by Chris Pine](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/) - You can read this in an afternoon to get a feel for the Ruby language.
- [The Well Grounded Rubyist by David Black](http://www.manning.com/black2/) - Like the title says it will give you an excellent grounding in the language.
- [Eloquent Ruby by Russ Olsen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321584104) - This book is sublime, it reads like a novel.
- [Ruby Best Practices by Gregory Brown](http://rubybestpractices.com/) - By this point you should be ready for the advanced level of this book.
- [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) - Fun tutorial you can complete in an afternoon.
- [Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) - Fantastic (and free) tutorial and I have heard his accompanying screencasts are amazing.
- [Agile Web Development with Rails by Sam Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) - By the time you are finished this you are now a completely capable Rails person!

Aside from books the most important thing is to get feedback on what you are doing. To do this I recommend spending time in irc.freenode.net #ruby and #rubyonrails. It is also extremely helpful to post things you are working on or having trouble with here on stackoverflow as the comments, explanations and different way of thinking about things that people provide are invaluable.

You should also definitely check out the [Ruby Rogues podcast](http://rubyrogues.com/), they provide invaluable information and the commentators are all extremely respected people in the Ruby community. And for your viewing and reading pleasure (in that order,) head over to Ryan Bates's [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) and  then Eifion Bedford's [Asciicasts](http://asciicasts.com/).

Finally, I recommend looking into different gems on github, reading the code and then contributing to them. You don't have to get overly ambitious and do massive recodes, especially at first. Just start with small things like editing and making the README files a little easier to read.

I don't use an IDE but at Railsconf I saw a demo of [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) from Jetbrains and it seemed pretty amazing.

Answer (score 6):

0) LEARN RUBY FIRST.  This is very important.  One huge advantage of Rails is Ruby: a great language that is very powerful but also marvelously easy to misunderstand.  Run through a few Ruby tutorials online.  When coding challenges come up on Daily WTF, write them in Ruby.  You'll pick it up fast.

1) Go buy the book "Ruby for Rails"

2) Check out a Rails tutorial and subscribe to the [Riding Rails](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/) blog.

3) Standup an app locally.  Don't use scaffolding.

4) When you install plugins into your app, go look at the code in that plugin (in your vendor directory) and learn it.  It is one of the best ways to learn Ruby and Rails internals.  When you don't understand how something works, post it here and 1,000 people will help you.

As for your other questions:

Yes, you will need a Linux environment to develop in.  You *can* develop Rails on Windows, but that doesn't mean it should be done.  Lots of gems aren't up to speed on Windows.

NetBeans works well as an IDE.  If you're on a Mac, you'll get street cred for using Textmate.

Comment: this does NOT work for everyone.  Please remember 1 hat doesn't fit all.  Learning ruby first is a fine idea but there's a reason the ruby language didn't go anywhere until rails come along.  Many developers want top use something with end results on the web right away and that's reasonable today.  A lot of ruby will not mean anything at all to people.  You can literally fall asleep after a few pages.  But with a practice web app to 'try' things on, things will start to make sense - as there is context.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised there has been so little mention of Why's (Poignant) Guide to Ruby. Why may not be around anymore but the guide is easy to find on the net ([Google points here first](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/)) it's a very easy read and provided my introduction to Ruby.

After the guide, I'd recommend either one of the books the others have suggested, or following  the series of screencasts at [Learning Rails](http://learningrails.com) which is how I picked up enough Ruby on Rails to be dangerous. Once you've completed the Learning Rails series. what you want to do with Rails will start to diverge from the general tutorials and that's where [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) becomes a wonderful tool. There's not much can be done with Rails that Railscasts hasn't touched on at some point.

Comment: While that's very true, I found it hard to understand what was going on in Rails without knowing more about Ruby syntax. I've made some changes to the my answer to better reflect the process.

Answer (score 5):

Find a nearby Ruby users group and start attending that.  I've found that is a great way to meet a lot of people who are passionate about development and willing to teach.

Answer (score 4):

My first suggestion would be to learn a little about [symbols](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/) first. Rails isn't the smallest framework ever, and while there's definitely lots to learn, most of it will start to make sense if you have at least a little bit of understanding what makes it different ("special") from other languages. As pointed out, there's no exact analog in any of the major languages, but they're heavily used by Rails, in order to make things read straightforwardly and perform well, which is the reason I brought it up. My very first exposure to Rails was also my first time looking at Ruby (well before 2.0), and the first thing that caught my eye was the goofy `:things` they were passing around, and I asked, "WTF is *that*?"

Also, check out [RubyQuiz](http://www.rubyquiz.com/), and read other peoples' answers on that site.

Answer (score 3):

I came from a Java background to Ruby to.  I found this tutorial helpful http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-java/. When it comes to learning rails I cannot say how much I use script\console.  It allows you to play with the code and learn how to do things that you are not sure about.

The only book I ever bought was Agile Web Development with Rails, Third Edition http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition.  It was quite useful and provided a good overview of the Rails framework.  In addition to that I regular watch Railscasts(http://railscasts.com), which is a great screen casting blog that covers all kinds of Rails topics.

I personally prefer using Linux (because git works better).  But, I have also used windows and besides git I do not think the OS choice will impact your programming.

I use netbeans for my IDE and occasionally vim (with the rails plugin).  I like netbeans but, I find that it can still be a little flaky when it comes to the Rails support (not all the features work all the time).

Comment: The fourth edition of agile web development is now out here: http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a great resource for people like me who are coming from PHP to RoR

http://railsforphp.com/ There's also a book [Rails for PHP Developers](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ndphpr)

Answer (score 3):

I used to do Java and C# on Windoze.

I'd second these sources:

**IDE**: Try Apatana RadRails 3 Sneak Peek: http://www.radrails.org/3. Its the closest thing you'll get to Visual Studio. I play with it here and there but still love the lightness of Textmate.

**OS**: Mac OS gets the most if not all love from Ruby community. Anything else is treated like a bastard child.

**Books**:

- The Pragmatic Programmers' Guide (the pickaxe book)
- Agile Web Development with Rails

**Screencasts**:

- Peepcode (pay) is a nice way to pick up concepts quickly
- [Railscasts (free)](http://railscasts.com/) is a good weekly way to pick up new gems and concepts incrementally
- [Railscasts (pro)](http://railscasts.com/pro) is also a good way to pick up concepts for a pretty low price.

Answer (score 2):

The ubber source for anything Rails is http://www.rubyonrails.org/ if they don't have it on the site you probably don't need it.

A quick cookbook is Ruby on Rails: Up and Running you can get it from O'Rielly or search Google for a on-line version. They walk you though the conventions of Rails and use Instant Rails which is ok.

A better Rails book "Agile Web Development with Rails" This is the soups to nuts of Rails. It walks you though downloading and setting up Rails, Gems, everything.

If you want are a Java 'guy' and want a transition book O'Reilly has "Rails for Java Developers" http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780977616695/?CMP=AFC-ak_book&ATT=Rails+for+Java+Developers

Answer (score 2):

Another IDE you could try is [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/rails).

Answer (score 2):

Oh I almost forgot.  Here are a few more Ruby screencast resources:

[SD Ruby](http://podcast.sdruby.com/) - the have a bunch of videos online - I found their Rest talks SD9 and SD10 to be among the best of the intros.  Other rest talks assume you know everything.  These ones are very introductory and to the point.

[Obie Fernandez](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/fernandez-restful-rails-apps) on InfoQ - Restful Rails.  I've also read his Rails Way book and found it informative but really long winded and meandering and the quality is a bit inconsistent.  I learned a lot from this book but felt it was a bit punishing to have to read through the repetition and irrelevant stuff to get to the good bits.

Netbeans is a nice hand holding IDE that can teach you a lot of language tricks if you have the patience to wait for its tooltips (it is a painfully slow IDE even on a really fast machine) and you can use the IDE to graphically browse through the available generators and stuff like that.  Get the latest builds and you even have Rspec test running built in.

[Bort](http://jimneath.org/2008/09/09/bort-base-rails-application/) is a prebuilt base app with a lot of the standard plugins already plugged in.  If you download it and play with it and figure out how it is setup you are about halfway to creating your own full featured apps.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is just to start - pick a small project that you would generally use to learn an MVC-style language (i.e. something with a database, maybe some basic workflow), and then as you need to learn a concept, use one (or both!) of

[Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)
or
The Rails Way

to learn about how it works, and then try it.

The problems with Agile Web Development are that it's outdated, and that the scenario runs on too long for you really to want to build it once; The Rails Way can be hard to follow as it bounces from reference to learning, but when it's good, it's better than Agile Web Development.

But overall they're both good books, and they're both good for learning, but neither of them provide an "education" path that you'll want to follow. So I read a few chapters of the former (enough to get the basic concepts and learn how to bootstrap the first app - there are some online articles that help with this as well) and then just got started, and then every few days I read about something new or I use the books to understand something.

One more thing: both books are much more Rails books than they are Ruby books, and if you're going to write clean code, it's worth spending a day learning Ruby syntax as early as possible. Why's Guide to Ruby is a good one, there are others as well.

Answer (score 2):

I bought the book "Simply Rails 2" by Patrick Lenz.
This book is a great introduction to Ruby and Ruby on Rails.
As for my ruby installation and db, I used Cygwin.
It comes with PostgreSQL, ruby and svn.
I like PostgreSQL because I come from an Oracle
background so it feels more comfortable than MySQL.

The other utility I found really useful was pgAdmin
for accessing the PostgreSQL databases.

The first thing I needed to do was to get gems installed.
I got the gems tar file from rubyforge
wget "http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/60718/rubygems-1.3.5.tgz"

Once I had gems setup, I installed

rails
ruby-postgres
postgres
rack

I also needed an issue tracking system so I installed redmine.
wget "http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/60718/rubygems-1.3.5.tgz"

I found that using a UNIX-like environment (Cygwin) was
preferable in my case because many of the tutorials were
taylored for OS X or Linux.

The text editor I use is Textpad.  I'm looking for an alternative.
I think that vim with the rails plugin might work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I come from a non-programming background. I have learned PHP on my own and recently joined a firm that specializes in Ruby on Rails. They have a comprehensive Rails training program, which is flexible enough to accommodate whatever changes we want to implement. Though I am not a rails pro, I would like to share my experience with rails. I hope that it helps.

Here is the path I am following [combined with tools I am using]

- Start with a simple ruby guide. It will help a lot, since entire rails framework revolves around classes and objects.
- Environment and OS are not important. Though I am working on a Mac, I frequently work on Linux and Windows, and I do not face any problems.
- Start with a good book which explains using a demo app. [I am using Agile Web Development with Rails - By The Pragmatic Bookshelf]. There are many other good books as well.
- Once you are done with the application, you will have a good idea of the framework.

  - Try to understand the SQL queries generated by Active Record module.
  - Go through the Rails Guides. You will find the framework a lot easier.
- Keep practicing.

Few imp points

- It takes years to learn a language completely. So be patient and do not stop learning.
- Go through rails api as when required. [While developing your first app]
- Google the things which you do not understand. People have written great articles on almost all topics.
- Use Stackoverflow :-) [Only when you are not able to find the solution on your own.]
- Load railscasts on your phone or video player. Watch 'em while travelling or in your free time. They are of few minutes each. You will learn a great deal of things and also learn the best way of doing things.

Tools

- Shell [in Mac and Ubuntu]
- Editor [Textmate in Mac, Gedit in Ubuntu and Notepad++ in Windows]
- Firefox with Firebug installed for testing.

Finally I have one thing to say "Keep trying". All the best.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to learn anything, Ruby on Rails included, is **pair programming.**

Find someone who knows Rails, pick an example app, sit down, and work through fixing bugs, adding features.

The knowledge sharing is unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the screencasts and short books from [Peepcode](http://peepcode.com/) are really good.  They have screencasts to get you started and have some as you get more advanced.

Answer (score 1):

There is a site called [Softies on Rails](http://www.softiesonrails.com/) that is written by a couple of ex-.NET developers that may be of some use. They have a book called [Rails for .NET Developers](http://pragprog.com/titles/cerailn/rails-for-net-developers) coming out in the next few months...

I started out on a Windows box using the [RadRails](http://www.aptana.com/rails) plugin for Eclipse and the [RubyWeaver](http://rubyweaver.gilluminate.com/) extension for Dreamweaver (back during the 1.x days of Rails). Since then I have moved to a Mac running TextMate and haven't thought of going back.

As for books, I started with The Ruby Way and Agile Web Development with Rails. It definately helps to build a background in Ruby as you start to make your way into Rails development.

Definately watch the Railscast series by Ryan Bates.

Answer (score 1):

I have found "The Rails Way" by Obie Fernandez excellent and often found myself referring to it when Agile Web Development with Rails didn't seem to go far enough. Obie Fernandez has a decent [blog](http://obiefernandez.com/) too.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a couple of months for [Learning Rails by Simon St. Laurent, Edd Dumbill](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596518776/?CMP=AFC-ak_book&ATT=Learning+Rails) to come out in November.  That series of books is stupendous, and this book will cover the latest version of Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get your environment up and running, this is helpful in giving you a basic app that users can log into.

Restful Authentication with all the bells and whistles:
http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=14216&p=1

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently learning RoR, here's what I've done so far: 
 1. Read, and followed, SitePoint's "Simply Rails 2.2"
 2. Read, and followed, Oreilly's "Rails, Up and Running" 2nd edition.

Those two books are very instructive, and take the same approach in different styles; the second book is a little more aggressive, which is good if you have some RoR knowledge.

As posted above, be extremely careful when reading resources, there are A LOT of outdated videos and articles.

Answer (score 1):

Good link for learning Ruby : 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming

Answer (score 1):

Just to +1 Agile Web Development with Rails (though make sure you get the latest edition) - http://pragprog.com/

I develop on a Mac and this can soemtimes be beneficial - it's quite a popular platform with Rails developers so many of the blog posts you look at will be mac-orientated. Linux is great too though ;)

Finally - and I have no connection with the company at all - when you do have something you want to put live, heroku is a good choice. Finding a cheap rails host isn't easy so this is a nice starting point. There are a lot of other great hosts out there too though! Heroku does kind of require git for version control (though you can use it on top of subversion).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Railscasts shmailcasts ...
1.  Think of some type app that you'd like to develop it.
2.  Take 20 minutes to napkin out some user flows
3.  Read the first couple of chapters of "Agile Web Development with Rails" with your project in mind
4.  Install Netbeans and rails on your windows or mac machine.  Either is just the same.
5.  Develop your app
6.  Consult the bajillion and one online references as you develop.

Answer (score 1):

The Book Agile Development with Rails is the number one teaching aid.  It's got a nice life-like(ish) application it builds up through the chapters as it introduces you to different concepts.  I worked through the examples twice, after which I had enough knowledge to do my own stuff and rely on the rails API documentation (http://api.rubyonrails.org/).

Answer (score 1):

To learn Ruby, read ["The Well-Grounded Rubyist" by David Black](http://www.manning.com/black2/). It is extremely clear, well-written, and well-organized. **The best technical book I've ever read** (out of maybe a dozen, since I'm a relatively new programmer).

To learn Rails, read "[Head First Rails](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596515775)." They explain how all the mysterious parts work together. Be patient with the silliness and work your way through the examples - it will pay off. (Also, for consistency, use whatever version of Rails they use. You can upgrade later.)

Both of these books assume little to no knowledge on your part, regarding OOP programming and MVC architecture. If you do know a bit, don't skim, because you might assume things incorrectly. (For instance, Ruby objects don't have public attributes, only getters and setters. But you can automatically create multiple getters/setters with a single line like `attr_accessor :attr1, :attr2, :attr3`.)

Answer (score 1):

Without a doubt

[Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)

and

The Rspec Book

and for fun

Advanced Rails Recipies

- I would link to the other two, but Stack Overflow won't let me.  See the same site.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the infamous "Blog in 15 minutes" video ages ago when Rails was probably around version 1.0 or something like that. One of the most important things about the Ruby/Rails world is that given it's great community it's changing ridiculously fast in comparison to other frameworks.

Today, Rails is significantly different that what it used to be, altho the main ideology has been kept the same. Having said that event tho in the lsat few years I've learnt a lot of things about Rails I still keep learning new things about it.

The most valuable resources to me that help me discovering and keeping up with the latest ways of doing Ruby and Rails are the following:

- [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) - A nice way of learning Rails itself, edited by the community, moderated by the core contributors. The site has a lot to offer on most of the important main topics around Rails that it can get you up and running very quickly. It covers bot the most recent stable and edge versions of the framework.
- If you understand the main ideology of Rails than I definitely recommend checking out (and subscribing to) Ryan Bates' [Railscasts](http://www.railscasts.com). Let me just quote from the site itself, I think it's pretty self explanatory:

  > Every week Ryan Bates will host a new
  >   Railscasts episode featuring tips and
  >   tricks with Ruby on Rails. These
  >   screencasts are short and focus on one
  >   technique so you can quickly move on
  >   to applying it to your own project.
  >   The topics target the intermediate
  >   Rails developer, but beginners and
  >   experts will get something out of it
  >   as well.
- There are also a lot of podcasts around Ruby/Rails, the two that I keep listening to are  [Ruby5](http://ruby5.envylabs.com/) and the [Ruby Show](http://rubyshow.com/).
- For more specific questions like API calls etc, I'd recommend APIDock's [Rails](http://apidock.com/rails) and [Ruby](http://apidock.com/ruby) sections where you can get more information on specific methods.
- If you are getting more familiar with the framework, it's worth taking a look at [Rails Best Practices](http://rails-bestpractices.com/). There's a bunch of short articles on certain issues that most people make in the beginning of their learning curve with Rails. This site is meant to point pot these issues and help beginners finding their way towards writing better and more well thought out code. There's also a [gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/rails_best_practices) that you could use which scans your application and points out these issues and offers solutions/workarounds. Pretty neat!

These resources should help you in getting up and running with Rails. Good luck with your journey to the Rails world and welcome to the community.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of good opinions here. I'll add what's not here. My experience:

- Rails on Windows is easy to get going with [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org), especially if you're using SQLite.
- If you want to use Ruby gems which need C extensions (e.g. RMagick), installation is difficult and unpredictable.
- PostgreSQL is a pain to install on Windows, and a pain to hook up to Rails.
- git doesn't work quite right on Windows.
- IDEs are bulky (Aptana). Notepad++ is good enough.
- Rails on Ubuntu is easy, and gems requiring C libraries just work.
- If your computer is powerful enough, use VirtualBox or VMWare Player, and use an Ubuntu Virtual Machine.

Setup Resources

- [This page](http://www.rubypluspl.us/2012/01/new-year-updated-ubuntu-rails-setup.html) shows, start to finish how to set up Ruby/Rails/PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 11.10.
- If you don't like RVM (I don't), use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). RVM and rbenv are tools for managing multiple versions of Ruby, including JRuby, Rubinius, etc.

Live Deployment for Development/Testing

- Live deployment lets your friends try out your app. It also makes it easier to interact with web services which need to make callbacks to your Rails server (such as PayPal IPN or Twilio).
- Heroku.com is my favourite place to deploy.
- localtunnel.com is a good utility to point a publicly visible URL to your local Rails server. (I have only used it for Windows-based Rails servers).

Learning

- Try out tutorials on the web.
- Use stackoverflow.com to ask questions.
- Use "raise Exception, params.to_s " in your Controllers to stop the app print out all the parameters which are driving your controllers. This gave me the greatest insight on how data is schlepped back and forth in a Rails app.
- Use the Rails console ("rails console") to inspect data, and try out code snippets before you embed them in your models or controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby:
I used Learn to program (in a weekend), Ruby Visual QuickStart (believe it or not this QS 
book was "off the hook" excellent). This took about a week.

Rails:
I just went through Learn Rails in one "aggressive" week. Definitely feel I have the nuts and bolts. It's 2009 which I deemed important!

Now I plan to combine a more advanced book with a real project.

IDE: VIM with rails plugin is great if you're a vim addict. Otherwise, try any suggested above.

Of course railscast, etc., are useful for most up to date stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My steps was:

```
* Agile development with Rails (book)
* Railscasts - very useful, always learn something new.
* And of course the RoR API
```

Answer (score 0):

Book : The Rails Way by Obie Fernandez 
IDE  : Netbeans or TextMate.

Answer (score 0):

My company has been developing [mavenlive.com](http://www.mavenlive.com), a knowledge management and decision support platform for three years.  Over the past few years we've learned a lot about rails and here are some of my recommendations.

1. Switch to Mac!  The tools that are available to you and the development environment on Mac allows you to be far more productive than on Windows.
2. railcasts.com has a wealth of informative screencasts from beginner to expert.  You can always find new and more efficient ways of doing things from Ryan's posts.
3. Scaling Rails screencasts coupled with NewRelic has provided powerful insight into the performance of our application and allows us to develop effectively while keeping our eyes open for future scalability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Read all the guides at [guides.rails.info](http://guides.rails.info), starting with [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rails.info/getting_started.html) They are well written, well organized, and up to date.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent source for learning Ruby and Ruby on Rails is at http://www.teachmetocode.com.  There are screencasts that cover the basics of Rails, along with a 6-part series on how to create a Twitter clone with Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have an article about [getting started with rails](http://kconrails.com/getting-started-with-ruby-on-rails/) that should help.  The only part of your question it doesn't cover is the OS.  Mac is the dominant player here, believe it or not!  But I use Ubuntu happily.  There are gedit plugins that get you very close to TextMate - in fact, I like gedit better.

If you're on a windows machine and can use linux, that's definitely a better way to go.  Rails on Windows has a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I learnt Ruby with the help of [Mr. Neighborly's Humble Little Ruby Book](http://www.humblelittlerubybook.com/). It's an excellent free-to-download introduction to Ruby with lots of examples, which I'd 100% recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Some awesome advice here!

Some of the resources I will list have been mentioned, some I don't think were.  I am definitely still not a pro, I've just been learning for the past few months and I've been improving at a rapid rate.  This is what helped me in order:

1. Why's poignant guide to ruby: excellent introduction to the Ruby language by the infamous _why.
2. Agile web development with rails book: great book with some good in-depth follow alongs
3. Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl (railstutotrial.org): this has been my favorite resource.  Hartl's style of walking you through demo apps and explaining everything just made things click for me.
4. Rails for Zombies - ran through this twice, great for reinforcing the basics.
5. Railscasts - I started following this along at first, but they were not helpful until now that I am just really starting to grasp Rails.  I would leave these for the end after you have got your feet wet.
6. Think Vitamin's rails tutorials were also pretty good. I followed along these screen casts at first, to feel out the language and then did them again towards the end.
7. The "Learning Rails" podcast, although outdated (Rails 2) was also a good starting resource. I listened to this while driving/working out.

I hope that was helpful! I'm far from being a pro, but I dove in head first and absorbed as much as I could from multiple resources.  The ones I mentioned above were the most helpful!

Oh and what's really helping me now is coming up with personal projects and settings certain tasks.  Following along is great, but you truly learn when you dive in without a guide!

Answer (score 0):

Try this book http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0):

This is also a good read
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning Rails now and if you're using Windows (assuming so with C# dev) I highly suggest learning on Linux if investing in a Mac is not an option.

If you don't want to to create a separate Partition on your HDD for Ubuntu, I suggest checking out [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer), a Windows installer for Ubuntu. The Rails experience is much less of a headache on Ubuntu than it is Windows and I'd argue is similar to that of an OSX dev environment, just not as much application support. I'm currently using a alpha text editor [Redcar](http://redcareditor.com/), which allows you to have some of textmate's functionality, the popular OSX editor.

Good books I've read on Rails are Beginning Rails 3 by Cloves Carneiro Jr and Rida Al Barazi. Also Rails Test Prescriptions by Noel Rappin, about developing in a test-driven approach.

My favorite things to keep me moving from amateur to notive are [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) by Ryan Bates. He usually releases a screencast every Monday or so about Rails gems, or recently Sass, SCSS, Coffeescript and technologies related to Rails 3.1.

A must read for any beginning programmer I feel is [why's (poignant) guide to ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/chapter-1.html). Unfortunately _why disappeared just as I was getting into Ruby, but his content is still scatter accross various sources. It has quirky humor and by the end you'll know Ruby's syntax quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with srboisvert. Don't do it on Windows. You can add Ubuntu (version of Linux) to Windows and have dual boot. It requires some work, but it is easier than going against the grain and trying to get everything working on Widows.

Ubuntu, Heroku and Git work wonderfully. Just know the learning curve is steep at first. Hire someone from Guru.com or Elance to help you.

Also, running Textmate on Mac is the preferred solution, so if you are considering getting a Mac or have access to one, that is the best thing to do. I don't think you need very much computing power...

Finally, my favorite book is Agile Web Development for Rails. Googling around doesn't work so well because most of the information is from old versions of Rails and is deprecated or doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I program with RoR on the Mac OS with textmate, and it's awesome.

I would suggest "Programming Ruby 1.9" (The Pickaxe Book) for Ruby and Agile Web Development with Rails" to learn Rails, both published by the Pragmatic Bookshelf.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question when I started out - hoping for a somewhat prescriptive guide on learning Rails... couldn't find one so decided I would write one for others who might find themselves in a similar boat one day :) You can find it here:

[Best Way to Learn Ruby & Rails](http://astonj.com/tech/best-way-to-learn-ruby-rails//)

(It's now actually returned with the !learn factoid helper in the official Ruby on Rails IRC chat room.)

Answer (score 0):

I have got up to speed with Ruby on Rails fairly quickly via this free online course which is currently being offered by UC Berkeley - [Software as a Service - Engineering Long Lasting Software](https://www.coursera.org/saas/auth/welcome) with instruction by [Armando Fox](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Faculty/Homepages/fox.html) and [David Patterson](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pattrsn/). I can't speak highly enough of this course... it really was a privilege to learn Rails from these guys. And there is an active community on the course forums if you run into difficulty along the way. The first offering of the online course has now finished (as of 25 March, 2012) - the next time it will be run will be sometime in September of 2012.

It assumes you are a fairly competent developer and gets you started on ruby in the second week, then Rails runs from the third week up to the end of the course (five weeks). Your assignments are marked by an auto-grader. You get provided with a pre-built Ubuntu VM image with everything you need for development pre-installed on it (e.g. Ruby, Rails, Rake, Gems, RSPec, Cucumber, etc). All you have to do is start up the VM inside the (free) VirtualBox software which runs on MacOSX, Windows and Linux.

There is a recommended text book for the course ... [here](http://beta.saasbook.info/) ... but you may be able to get by looking at the lectures and screencasts online.