# Starting off with Ruby and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am interested in building web applications using Ruby on Rails. I surfed the Internet and found out that I need to have a prior knowledge of the Ruby language. So can you please suggest some good books, online resources to start off with Ruby first and then Ruby on Rails?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: There must be around thousand questions and answers on SO regarding this very query. Search for them please.

Comment: 2 years old, but still relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574/learning-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as Ruby goes, two good books are:

1. Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmers' Guide by Dave Thomas, Chad Fowler, and Andy Hunt
2. The Ruby Way, Second Edition: Solutions and Techniques in Ruby Programming by Hal Fulton

Check out this link also for some helpful sites: 
http://ruby.about.com/od/tutorialsontheweb/tp/10waysfree.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may also find [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/) is useful too. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also Why's famous guide: http://poignant.guide/book/

Answer (score 0):

i also find above mentioned site Ruby on Rails tutorial quite helpful.. After this i suggest you can refer some of mentioned books to gain more experience in this language and framework.

```
* The Ruby Programming Language
* Rails 3 Way,
* Advanced Rails Recipes
```