# Silverlight developer, learning ruby, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As said in title I'm SL developer and want to learn ruby and after adopt rails. Which books/resources/screencasts you can recomend to get up and running quickly?
I'll use Linux and chosed Netbeans as IDE but if i won't like it i'll use gedit. What can you say about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go nuts on an IDE. just use a text editor.

If you're on silverlight:

- Pay for this [git screencast](http://peepcode.com/products/git) at peepcode
- Buy the beta version of [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) (covers rails3)

Build the Depot store using the book and you'll fall in love.

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby, the Pickaxe book is still the standard reference.
http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9

For Rails snippets, it's hard to go wrong with Railscasts.
http://railscasts.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might consider jumping straight into rails if that is your end-goal. Checkout http://railstutorial.org/book

Answer (score 0):

I use both the [PragProg Rails book](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) and [The Rails Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321445619) by Obie Fernandez. The first works well as an introduction, the second works better as a reference. If you have to choose one, honestly I'd go with RW.

Ryan Bates' [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/) are essential.

All of the [peepcode](http://peepcode.com/) rails material is worth purchasing. If you're coming from a mostly Windows world as I was, the Unix screencasts are just as important as the rails stuff. I bought the year subscription and haven't regretted it.

Although I find the organization and overall tone not really my cup of tea, the content of [Metaprogramming in Ruby](http://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) has been extremely helpful in understanding many of the Rails idioms. I'd say understanding the techniques in this book are as essential as anything else. Once you're comfortable in the basic Rails framework, spend some time here. There will be a ceiling on your productivity if you don't dive in to metaprogramming concepts, and although it's essential to Rails, there's really nothing analogous to that style in the Java/.NET world.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching StackOverflow first :) [Learning Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574/learning-ruby-on-rails)