# Getting intimidating looking at /config files in projects at github, is there a book that covers this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking at some open source apps on github, specifically the files in the /config folder like:

boot.rb, application.rb, etc.

They seem too complicated!

Is there a book that details all of this?

I'm finding the basics easy to understand, but configuration, setup is always a tricky part and a solid book on these topics would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Agile Web Development With Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition) is pretty much the gold standard. There are some other good resources listed in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574/learning-ruby-on-rails).

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.  It'll walk you from beginner (even installing the app) to everything you need to know to get started.

Comment: i've read it! it doesn't cover this stuff, like look at this:http://github.com/bestbuyremix/BBYIDX/blob/master/config/boot.rb

Comment: Hmm. Well I suppose that's true. As it says at the top of the file, the configuration settings go in `environment.rb`, which is pretty well documented. I guess the literal answer to your question is "No".

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the config files, those are discussed usually throughout a Rails book, such as database.yml in the introduction chapter, and routes.rb in the Routing chapter.

The other important ones are: `environment.rb` and the 3 files under `environments` folder, one for each of `production`, `development`, and `test`.  These six files are some of the most often used ones.

A Rails Guide section that talks about config is:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

It may be good to learn it step by step to get a good foundation.  A free online tutorial is at

http://railstutorial.org/book
http://railstutorial.org/

There are lots of high quality Ruby on Rails screencast too:

http://railscasts.com/
http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts

To get a complete folder from GitHub, you can first install `git`, and then do a

```
git clone http://github.com/nex3/haml.git
```

and you will see a new folder in the current directory on your hard drive, with everything in the project in that folder.