# Missing image 404 error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application , in some pages for the user images it showing like

```
<img title="myname" src="/appname/datas/thumb50/missing.png" class="user_profile_image" alt="MYNAME">
```

which shows a 404 error..
I am very new to ROR.. Dont know how to rectify the error.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
"/appname/datas/thumb50/missing.png"
```

Should surely be the relative path to your public directory or actual path:

```
"/datas/thumb50/missing.png"
```

or

```
"http://www.domain.com/datas/thumb50/missing.png"
```

These assumes the directory 'datas' lies in your public path.

Comment: @Aruna, you *must* get a good rails book! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574/learning-ruby-on-rails