# rollback generated controller/model in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I created, using the scaffolding, a model and controller files.
Later I discovered it would be a good idea to create the tables in the DB first...
My question, How can I role back the generated files and regenerate them now, that I have the tables in the DB?

I just started learning RoR, so right now I am not interested in best practices, just learning the tool box this FW (RoR) comes with.

And, do you have a recommendation for a good tutorial? I do know to use google, it is just that search engines don't know, yet (working on that), how to grade tutorials.
**Edit:** For my last question I found [Learning Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574/learning-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

try

```
rails destroy scaffold XXXXX
```

one thing that I find puzzling though is that you said "Later I discovered it would be a good idea to create the tables in the DB first..."

Well, rails creates a [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) file for you when you run the generator in the first place, and this file will create your DB tables and fields when you run it using `rake db:migrate`

PS - here's a few good tutorials for you:

- [rails tutorial ebook](http://railstutorial.org)
- [rails demo site](http://arailsdemo.com)
- [rails 4 zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/)

Comment: yeah, i just do `rails destroy scaffold Post` to remove posts resource (note the capitalization)

Answer (score 19):

You can rollback controller.

```
rails destroy controller [controller]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete all the files Rails created -- just look at the printout on your command line, see what files rails created, and delete them.

I don't know why you would want to create all the tables in the db, but that's fine, I guess. I prefer to let rails do it. Either way, Rails won't mind. You can always add / change fields using Rails, even if you created the tables outside Rails.

Ryan Bates' Railscasts are excellent tutorials.