# Guides and books for learning how to program Ruby on Rails Apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574/learning-ruby-on-rails)

I am all new to programming and what to produce userfriendly and interactive web- and mobile apps.

What guides and books would you recommend to get started programming in Ruby on Rails on the Mac?

Is RoR a good choice for creating apps that also can be converted and integrated into mobile apps?

It´s mainly some portals, social communites/dating sites, etc I want to create.

Comment: Consider google. This has been answered waaay to many times. Look at other questions.

Comment: Agreed with Olof. This question has been asked at least 4,213 times.

Answer (score -1):

Seriously. This is the best. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book. Come back in a week when you know things better. Yes, rails is good. But I personally don't like it.  Also look at early episodes of Railscasts. http://railscasts.com. (Yes I know that rails now is rails 3 but a lot of things are the same).

I should also mention that ruby language is slow (I have no experiance developing rails at all but some "ruby sites" takes 3 seconds to load which I find annoying. Of course this has to to with how you host the site).

Rule of thumb. Learn Ruby first (very very important, same can be said for php, python...). *The ruby programming language* (and one more book, don't remember the title) is very good for learning Ruby. First when you know Ruby syntax, then learn Rails.