# How should I learn Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a Java developer and I really want to get into Rails. What have you found to be the best way to learn RoR?

Seriously, any tips/tricks/rants would be awesome.

Comment: Maybe learn Ruby first.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/55574/128421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd definitely recommend using Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) book. I've also found Daniel Kehoe's [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) e-book super helpful as well.

On a personal level, finding a project I actually wanted to build, as opposed to just pacing through a tutorial, is what really helped get me off the ground though.