# I am totally new to ruby on rails. But I am very much keen to learn it. So where should I start from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to learn Ruby on Rails from the root. I want to build my career Ruby on Rails. As I am totally new to this language, I am looking for guidance.

Comment: You can check best sources to learn ROR [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574/learning-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more interactive approach to learning, try [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) or [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Best site is http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html to start with rails

Also try creating an app along with it https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Answer (score 0):

These are the new guides for Rails 4.2 based on v4.2.5.1. These guides are designed to make you immediately productive with Rails, and to help you understand how all of the pieces fit together.

```
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

Lot of great places to start, here to name a few:

**FREE:**

- Rails Official Guide
- Railscasts
- Open source projects

**PAID:**

- Treehouse
- Upcase
- Code School

**BOOKS:**

- Ruby on Rails tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book **[FREE]**
- Agile Web Development with Rails 4
- Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec

If you have some money to spend I would definitely recommend Treehouse for beginning